# How to do auto synch to make app work online and offline

Tags: objective-c, ios7

How to do auto synch to make app work online and offline

Comment: Are you using any library for networking?

Comment: Is your question about storing data or checking internet or both ?

Comment: when user out of network and whenever comes in network want to upload on sever whatever stored in databse

Comment: please do some research about reachability framework.

Comment: How to do auto synch to make app work online and offline

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Data for local storage.
You can do the upload functionality whenever the net is connected by using NSNotificationCenter in the Reachability code.
Please refer the Reachability class sample code from the apple developer site.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html